# Automapper - ignore property that exist only in ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am trying to map Model ViewModel, using Automapper 8.1, but it does not work because I have property in ViewModel that I dont have in my Model, I am getting "unmapped member" exception

Model:

```
 public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class DepartmentViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfEmployees{get;set}

}
```

MapperConfiguration:

```
 CreateMap<Department, DepartmentViewModel>()
            .ForMember(d => d.NumberOfEmployees, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

The only way I can make it work is adding NumberOfEmployees property to my Model with [NotMapped] annotation.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: is your mapper configuration complete, or is there more going on that is not included in the question?

Comment: Hi, Lucian will try to make gist. @jcwmoore in mapper configuration I have only other created maps and averything works fine except this one.

Comment: I have changed mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DepartmentViewModel>>(departments) to  return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<IDepartment>>(departments) and now it works.